# How to create Yii2 ActiveForm field with multiple HTML classes

Tags: html, forms, yii2, active-form

I'm struggling to use Yii2's ActiveForm to create the specific HTML/CSS styling I want. This HTML code below (with css applied) creates a form field with the icon *inside* of it and the submit button *inside*.

```
<form action="" class="form form--type">
            <i class="bpi bpi--icon"></i>
            <input type="email" class="field field--style-round" placeholder="Email address">
            <button type="submit" class="button button--style-default">
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
```

Everything between the opening and closing form tags is included in the form. I basically need to create a field for a Yii2 ActiveForm that includes all that html and displays it properly.

I've tried keeping that HTML in place and putting $form->field() where < input type> is but the icon and submit button end up outside of it. Right now, I've tried passing that styling in using textInput($options = []) like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput($options = 
         [
              'class' =>
                   ['form form--type-input-button-split', 'bpi bpi--email', 'field field--style-round'], 
              'placeholder' => 'Your email address',
              'button' =>
                   ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'button button--style-default']
         ])?>
```

But it doesn't display the icon or submit button inside the field like I need (the button doesn't appear at all). I'm sure I'm not setting up the button right in that array, but in general, how do you create a Yii2 form field with several specific html elements (like < i>, < button>) inside of the form field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parts](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#$parts-detail) property and [templete](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#$template-detail) property of an active field to configure html of an input, for example:

```
$form->field($model, 'email', [
  'parts' => [
    '{icon}' => '<i class="bpi bpi--icon"></i>',
    '{button}' => '<button type="submit" class="button button--style-default">Submit</button>'
  ],
  'template' => "{label}\n{icon}{input}{button}\n{hint}\n{error}"
])->textInput($options[
  'class' => 'form form--type-input-button-split bpi bpi--email field field--style-round'], 
  'placeholder' => 'Your email address',
])?>
```

Also you can configure these property for each field of form, for example:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
  'id' => 'myform',
  'fieldConfig' => [
    'parts' => [
      '{icon}' => '<i class="bpi bpi--icon"></i>',
      '{button}' => '<button type="submit" class="button button--style-default">Submit</button>'
    ],
    'template' => "{label}\n{icon}{input}{button}\n{hint}\n{error}"
  ],
]);
```

Comment: With that code, it still displays the icon above my field and the submit button below it :/ 

`"{icon}{input}{button}\n{hint}\n{error}"`

 Is there any way to make sure icon, input, button are all in the field, maybe in the same row?

Or is there a way to add it inside textInput?

Comment: @user3505195, You must use CCS to positioning of your html elements

Comment: I have the CSS already, when I use just the html in my question, it displays properly. The styling I'm looking to mimic in Yii has a single field with an icon appearing inside of it and the submit button being inside of the form as well. Using the template still had the submit button below (and separate from) the field.  Is there a way when I create a form field and call textInput() that a submit button is also included in that same form field? Not sure if that question makes sense